# Why is that the UI is not refreshed when data is updated in typescript and angularjs program

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, typescript

I learn typescript and angularjs for a few days,and now I have a question that confuses me for days, I want to make a gps tracking system, so I try to write a service like this:

1.

```
  module Services {
        export class MyService {
            getGpsPeople(): Array<AppCommon.GPSPerson> {
                var gpsPeople = new Array<AppCommon.GPSPerson>()
                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    var tempPerson = new AppCommon.GPSPerson({ name: "username" + i.toString() });
                    gpsPeople.push(tempPerson);
                }
                return gpsPeople;
            }
        } // MyService class
    }
```

2. A controller like this:

   module AppCommon {
   export class Controller {
   scope: ng.IScope;

   ```
        constructor($scope: ng.IScope) {
            this.scope = $scope;

        }
    }
   ```

   }
   module Controllers {

   ```
    export interface IMyScope extends ng.IScope {

        gpsPeople: Array<AppCommon.GPSPerson>;
    }

    export class MyController extends AppCommon.Controller {
        scope: IMyScope;

        static $inject = ['$scope','myService'];
        constructor($scope: IMyScope,service:Services.MyService) {
            super($scope);

            $scope.gpsPeople = service.getGpsPeople();
        }
    }
   ```

   }

3.The GPSPerson class like this:

```
 export class GPSPoint {
        latitude = 0;
        longtitude = 0;

        constructor(la: number, lg: number) {
            this.latitude = la;
            this.longtitude = lg;
        }
    }

    export interface IPerson {
        name: string;
    }

    export class GPSPerson  
    {
        name: string;
        lastLocation: GPSPoint;
        countFlag = 1;
        historyLocations: Array<GPSPoint>;
    
        timerToken: number;
        startTracking() {
            this.timerToken = setInterval(
                () => {
                    var newGpsPoint = null;
                    var offside = Math.random();

                    if (this.countFlag % 2 == 0) {
                        newGpsPoint = new GPSPoint(this.lastLocation.latitude - offside, this.lastLocation.longtitude - offside);
                    }
                    else {
                        newGpsPoint = new GPSPoint(this.lastLocation.latitude + offside, this.lastLocation.longtitude + offside);
                    }

                    this.lastLocation = newGpsPoint;
                    this.historyLocations.push(newGpsPoint);
                    console.log(this.countFlag.toString() + "+++++++++++++++++++" + this.lastLocation.latitude.toString() + "----" + this.lastLocation.longtitude.toString());
                    this.countFlag++;
                }
                , 10000);
        }

        stopTracking() {
            clearTimeout(this.timerToken);
        }

        constructor(data: IPerson) {
            this.name = data.name;
            this.lastLocation = new GPSPoint(123.2, 118.49);
            this.historyLocations = new Array<GPSPoint>();
        }
    }
```

The problem is:

1.Should I make the GPSPerson class a Controller?

2.The setinterval works but the UI dose not change(when I hit button ,it changes,the button do nothing )?

I'm a beginner of ts and angular,and have no experience with js, I do not know if I have explained it clearly, hope someone can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> setInterval works but the ui dose not change

This is because the angular `$digest` loop does not run on completion of `setInterval`. You should use `$interval` service https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval as that tells Angular to do its dirty checking again.

You just need to provide `MyService` access to `$interval` though. Inject it using `$inject` (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yis8m3BdnEM&hd=1).

> 1.should i make the GPSPerson class a Controller?

No. Its an array of JavaScript objects inside the controller and that is fine.

Comment: your suggestion is really helpful,according to your answer,i modify myService,inject a $interval into it,and pass it and the service itself as a constructor parameter to GPSPerson,refresh the lastPostion property every 1000ms(get new postion from the service),it works,i just wonder,i pass the same $interval object to every item of the array,will it be a problem? and  if the service task costs time more than 1000ms,will it skip to next service call and ignore the current task?

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the tracking logic and keep just the data in GPSPerson. For the tracking logic I would make a factory.
My examples are not in Typescript but I'm sure you will have no problem in converting the code if you want.

This is a link to a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/VRMByWVhGioRjxnn9yzP?p=preview)

I've made a much simpler example but I think you'll understand the idea.
The factory would have two methods for start and stop tracking. They will take a person as parameter.

```
app.factory('tracking',function($interval){
  var trackingInterval;
  var trackingFn = function(person){
    var currentPos = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    var newPosition = {id:person.positions.length, position:currentPos};
    person.positions.push(newPosition);
  };
  var startTracking = function(person){
    person.interval = $interval(function(){
      trackingFn(person);
    },2000);

  };

  var stopTracking = function(person){
    console.log('STOP');
    $interval.cancel(person.interval);
  };
  var getNewTrack = function(){
  };
  return {
    startTracking: startTracking,
    stopTracking: stopTracking,
  };
});
```

I've also made a very simple directive to show the data

```
app.directive('position',function(){
  return {
    templateUrl: 'positionTemplate.html',
    link: function(scope, element,attrs){
    }
  }
});
```

and the template look like this

```
<div>
  <button ng-click="startTracking(person)">Start tracking</button>
  <button ng-click="stopTracking(person)">Stop tracking</button>
  <p>{{person.name}}</p>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="pos in person.positions">{{pos.position}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the directive would be called this way

```
<div ng-repeat="person in people">
  <div position></div>
</div>
```

I'm not saying that this is a better solution but that is how I would do it. Remember it is just a model and needs a lot of improvement.